# Use of "Would" with "Have"

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Please explain the use of "would" with "have". Can we use them together twice in a sentence. If not then why?

Comment: What do you mean "twice" in a sentence? Can you provide an example? "Would have" is perfectly valid.

Comment: "I would have done that if you would have given me some time." Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

> **"I would have done that if you would have given me some time." Is it correct?**

No.

*would have done* is already conditional; placing it in an *if* clause makes it double-conditional. This usage is invalid.

**Correct usage:**

> I would have done that if you had given me some time.
>
> I would have done that if it were possible.

Comment: You mean double conditional clause is incorrect?

Comment: Not always, but in your example, yes. Double *would have* is never correct. One example of valid double conditional: *I would have done that if you could have given me more time.*

Comment: Cool , glad to help.

Comment: :) what is your name?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial question, although it is a very basic one. In one use of "would" I understand it to imply how things might be if circumstances differ from what they are now. If it rains, I would shelter. If there were no bread, I would eat cake. If I were rich, I would have money. Without a lifejacket I would have lost my life. In this last example, I am saying that I had a lifejacket (so am still alive) but that if I had not had one, I would now be dead.

This shows that you may write "would have". I regret I cannot tell you all the uses of "would": it is a long matter to explain properly. Other people's answers will tell you better than I would have done.

Answer (score 0):

## 'Would' paired with 'have' has several uses.

Present tense: 'I would have you know that I'm tired today.' In this case, 'would' means 'wish to', though it's a slightly archaic usage.

Conditional (Past) tense: 'I would have slept better, but it was too hot last night.'

Conditional (Future) tense: 'If I drank much more coffee, I would have to use the restroom quite urgently.'

Though the different uses can be used in a sentence together successfully, it is likely to be cumbersome.

'I would have you know that if you would have stolen that watch, I would have to have reported you.'

### Using either multiple Conditional clauses, or merely multiple versions of the same phrase in one sentence, can be confusing. Try to phrase your sentences clearly without such repetition.

The example sentence above could more clearly read:

'I just want you to know that if you had stolen that watch, I would have been required to report you.'

Comment: Very helpful indeed